# How to get the text from inside a list of items in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So im trying to scrape some data from a website, and I cant get just the text from the html, I need to extract the data and put it in a CSV file in a single column.

I've tried different steps, like looping trough the index, but If I do this, I cant get the whole list of founders(if there are more than one) in a single column.

```
    for panel in panel.find_all('p', class_='content-group'):
            fondateur = panel.find_next_siblings('b')
            print(fondateur)
```

this is what I get:

```
    [<b>Alexandre Bilger</b>, <b>Fabrice de Salaberry</b>, <b>Olivier Gaunet</b>, <b>Cyril De Maleprade</b>]
    [<b>Anne OSDOIT</b>, <b>Gerard HASCOET</b>]
    [<b>Claude Avisse</b>]
    [<b>Nicolas NAIGEON</b>]
    [<b>Jérôme Varnier</b>, <b>Romain Melloul</b>, <b>Vincent Oliveira</b>]
    [<b>Clémentine GUYON </b>, <b>Clémence COURSIMAULT </b>]
    [<b>Maxim  Romain</b>]
```

And what I expect is just the names.

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can see what information do you need extract?

Comment: this is the site: https://www.myfrenchstartup.com/fr/startup-france/235134/tribvn_healthcare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you already scraped the correct elements.

from here, you just need to use `getText()` on each element to get the text content, and "flatten" the list using a list comprehension.

try this:

```py
names = [fondateur.getText() for panel in panel.find_all('p', class_='content-group') for fondateur in panel.find_next_siblings('b')]

print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used BS but it is returning Lists for you using find_next_siblings.

it looks like you can just loop over that.

try this instead:

```
for panel in panel.find_all('p', class_='content-group'):
    for name in panel.find_next_siblings('b')
        print(name)
```

you will still have the bold tags around them, that can be your next step of learning.

Comment: If I do this I only get one name of the founders, I have to get all the names